# Is there any api to get keystone notification events?

Tags: events, rabbitmq, openstack, keystone, ceilometer

The only information I found is that you can view those events through ceilometer or RabbitMQ. Would be nice if I can get those events directly through APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to get notifications from individual OpenStack services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Each of the openstack services have 'exchanges' and 'topics' in rabbitmq

you can use Rabbitmq to connect to these exchanges and topics to get notifications via messages.